# Reload SwiftUI View for specific elements

Tags: github, promise, line, swiftui

In my SwiftUI code, I create a view called `LineView()` (this is from the graph library for swift on github [here](https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView)). I am trying to generate data from it using the function `firestoreManager().getUserData()`. There are many moving pieces in this piece of code and I will try to explain them. The `User` datatype is a user, the `userInfo.updateStockChart()`gives the updated data. However, that isn't important. What is important is that the code in the `firestoreManager.getUserData()` closure runs after the `LineView()` creation code (note that the closure code uses the google [swift promise library](https://github.com/google/promises) to run). I need that code to run BEFORE the `LineView()`. Any Ideas?
I have tried to solve this many ways, but since the VStack is strongly tied to the struct, I am not sure how.

```
struct homepageView: View {

@State var data: [Double] = [0,1,2]
var body: some View {
    var userInfo: User = User(username: "", name: "", portfolioID: "", friendList: [])
    var theData: [Double] = self.data
    firestoreManager().getUserData(collection: "Users", documentVar: "darrow_h19", documentField: "Username").then{ user in
        userInfo = user
        theData = userInfo.updateStockChart(portfolioID: "123456")
        print(theData)
    }
    print(theData)
    return VStack {
        LineView(data: theData, title: "$XYZ", legend: "Hello World",totalPoints: 18,yPosChange: 300)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't need that. Instead your `LineView` (or `homepageView`) has to react asynchronously on data received from service.

Comment: Whatever is in the `.then{}` clause will execute after all other code, regardless of line order. Try moving the `LineView()` creation code inside the `.then{}`.